# Is it possible to use keywords params with DataTestMethod of MSTest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parameters, mstest

Wanting to make an unit test prettier, I've replaced all the parameters by a single array using the keyword `params`. It gave me the following.

```
[DataRow("field1", "field1", "field2", "field2")]
[DataTestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidJsonDataFieldException))]
public void Parse_ShouldThrow_GivenOrderIsWrong(params string[] fieldReads)
{
    //Doesn't reach this point
    ...
}
```

So, `string fieldRead1, string fieldRead2, string fieldRead3, string fieldRead4` became `params string[] fieldReads` which is neater I believe. Everything compile, but when launching the test it return the following error and doesn't even reach the first line.

> Test method threw exception
>   System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException, but exception
>   MyNamespace.MyException was expected. Exception message:
>   System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Nombre de paramètres
>   incorrects.

So it definetly has trouble handling it.
Do you guy know a smart twist to make it work?
I know this isn't a big deal, but I'm curious anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be writing your own DataRowAttribute:

```
public class MyDataRowAttribute : DataRowAttribute, ITestDataSource
{
    public MyDataRowAttribute(object data1) : base(data1)
    { }

    public MyDataRowAttribute(object data1, params object[] moreData) : base(data1, moreData)
    { }

    public new IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        string[] data = base.Data.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
        object[] arguments = new object[] { data };

        return new List<object[]> { arguments };
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
[MyDataRow("field1", "field1", "field2", "field2")]
[DataTestMethod]
public void SampleTest(params string[] fieldReads)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(4, fieldReads.Length);
}
```